# Logstash drop filter not dropping/filtering info level logs

Tags: logging, logstash

I have what I think would be a pretty basic filter. I want logstash to drop all 'info' level logs as what we are doing produces so many logs we need to cut volume, and as a test we are going to cut the superfluous info level logs. However it doesn't appear to be dropping ANY info level logs.

```
filter {
  if [loglevel] == "info" {
    drop { }
  }
  date {
    match => [ bunch of stuff ]
    timezone => "UTC"
    remove_field => syslog_timestamp"
  }
  mutate {
  add_field => [ stuff ]
  add_field => [ stuff ]
  add_tag => [ stuff ]
  }
}
```

Am I using it wrong? It appears to match what's in the docs for a drop filter. Not sure what's going on. Thanks!

[image: Log]

Comment: == is string equality, so it is case sensitive. Do your logs really have "info" rather than "INFO"?

Comment: I've done upper/lower and a regex so case doesn't matter. No change in the log volume. Still spewing info logs.

Comment: Update your question with the json of a message that should have been dropped so it helps to understand what is happening, if the events are not being dropped, your conditional is not working for some reason.

Comment: Our logstash.conf has 3 stanzas. Input, output, and filter, in that order.  Does the order matter? Would filter have to be between input and output? I don't think that's the case.  

I have edited the OP to include a screenshot from our Kibana that is the endpoint for syslogs via logstash

Comment: Are you parsing your `message` field? Do you have a field named `log_level` in your document? Your conditional tests on the `loglevel` field, do you have this field in your document? The order of `input`, `filter` and `output` does not matter, just the order of the filters in each block.

Comment: I am not parsing the message field.  The log source is Cloud Foundry and some components send it as 'loglevel'. some as 'log_level', and others as just 'level'.  I've tried to filter just one to make it simple but those messages still come through. Just can't seem to crack why this drop filter is not doing anything.

Comment: Ok I think I am onto something here and could use some help with syntax.  My problem all along is that level, or log_level are not their items. They are embedded within the "message" data.  So now I need to filter based on that.  What I need is basically:

if [message] =~ "level":"info" { drop { } }

I'm not sure how to properly handle that syntax as the quotes mess things up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your field is called [log_level], not [loglevel], so change your conditional to be

```
if [log_level] == "info" { drop { } }
```

The order of the input / filter / output stanzas does not matter. Order within the filter stanza obviously does.

Comment: Good catch. So some sources use loglevel and some use log_level so I included both in my filter and it's not filtering either. Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason log_level and/or level were part of the message instead of their own key/value.  The solution was looking for the particular string and filtering if it existed.  ie

```
filter {
  if '"log_level":"info"' in [message] {
    drop { }
  }
}
```

That filtered all of the log_level:info messages and reduced our log count by 65% or so.